# How do I determine if a .NET Core application is currently running on linux

Tags: process

How do I determine if a specific .NET Core application is currently running on Linux and isn't failing, if it's application log shows no data?

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef | grep {application_name or part of it}
```

will list all active/current processes with "{application_name or part of it}" in the results.